# My web site has been shut down because someone added some sort of malware

Tags: malware

My web site has been shut down because someone added some sort of malware The host is Go daddy and the platform is wordpress. I am not able to get into the website to remove the malware.  The web site is a .co  I have tried various things but i do not seem to be getting anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: I would say take it up with Go Daddy.

Comment: You being unable access your site isn't something we can help with.  There are existing questions about what to do if you discover your website has been hijacked though.  You will have to be more specific then "I tried various things" what things exactly?

Comment: The fact that you mention WordPress sends chills down my spine. I helped a user on here in the past which had the exact same issue. In the end, the user had actually downloaded and installed a paid plug-in for "free" from a sketchy site which had malware code in it. The user deleted their question from the site soon after.

Comment: You may need to contact your hosting provider, I believe they do daily backup, please just make restoration. :)

I found interesting article on gplus 2 days ago, please read http://bit.ly/1F7DPzk, why your wordpress site being attacked

Answer (score 2):

Your web-site has multiple components

Registrar - The organization whom you purchased the Domain from.

Hosting - Who you host your web-site (Pages and other consumable data) with.

It is possible that you have both of these service with GoDaddy.  If so you will need to handle this with them.  You need to find what the "Violation"  that has caused your domain or hosting account to become disabled.